# Как в mysql изменить тип поля

Tags: mysql

Надо сделать поле чтобы можно записывать в него числа типа `65.5`, а сейчас можно только целые числа писать.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос, как определено поле на данный момент.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `column_name` `column_name` FLOAT;
```

table - имя вашей таблицы
column_name - имя вашего поля